# Decrypt using public key, RSA and Bouncy castle

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I need to decrypt a signature hash using RSA. I've got a hexadecimal string of 288 characters long which is a general public key from an institution. It represents hexadecimal bytes, so 144 bytes total.
The first 8 bytes are the so called CAR. Which is used for identification. The next 128 bytes are the Modulus N. And the next 8 bytes are the exponent E.

I've never worked with cryptography before so go easy on me. I'm using C# and the [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) library for the decryption algorithms. Now, If I understand correctly, a 1024 bit modulus and 64 bits exponent is not strange. I currently have this bit of code:

```
public byte[] rsa_decrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        
        var N = PublicKey.ToCharArray().Slice(16,256);
        var E = PublicKey.ToCharArray().Slice(272,16);

        RsaEngine rsa = new RsaEngine();
        Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger modulus = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(new string(N).Insert(0,"00"),16);
        Console.WriteLine(modulus);
        Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger exponent = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(new string(E).Insert(0,"00"),16);
        Console.WriteLine(exponent);
        RsaKeyParameters x = new RsaKeyParameters(false,modulus,exponent);
        var eng = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
        eng.Init(false,x);
        return eng.ProcessBlock(data,0,data.Length);
    }
```

The `Slice<T>(this T[],offset,length)` method is just a small thing I wrote to cut arrays in pieces, nothing special and it works. The insertion of the "00" in the string is because the string could otherwise be interpreted as unsigned I believe.

When I run this code I get the exception

`Unhandled exception. Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: block incorrect at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings.Pkcs1Encoding.DecodeBlock(Byte[] input, Int32 inOff, Int32 inLen) at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings.Pkcs1Encoding.ProcessBlock(Byte[] input, Int32 inOff, Int32 length)`

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong, why I'm doing it wrong, and most preferably, what I should be doing. Again, never worked with crypto algorithms or this library ever before.

Comment: The RSA exponent is usually always 65537. A 1024 bit modulus is common for older RSA keys. For the signature data you can check if it is something in ASN.1 format by pasting it here https://lapo.it/asn1js/

Comment: I got the exponent en modulus in a hexadecimal ASCII string from a file. I made a bigInteger from the exponent and it is indeed 65537. Unfortunately, I can't check the data format using the link you gave. It's to big, the site says it has to be under... 40? bytes or whatever, but thanks for the tip.